# does netfilter-persistent reload open up the gates for half a moment?

Tags: iptables, vpn, firewall

I have iptables set up to block all outgoing traffic that tries escape outside my VPN connection. and netfilter-persistent to make iptables rules persistent. this all works perfectly.

Now because connecting IPs change from time to time, I want to make a script that looks up IPs and updates iptables whitelist rules on an hourly basis.

Two related questions on this..

1. **Whenever the script reloads the netfilter-persistent service to update iptables, is there a split second where traffic could escape outside VPN? or are new rules overwritten without a full flush first?**
2. **and how about during a system reboot? do the network interfaces come up before netfilter-persistent kicks in or is there a possibility for non-VPN traffic to escape during boot-up?**

I feel it's only logical in both cases it should be safe from 'leakage' , but couldn't find anything confirming this.

Comment: Related: The potential impact [is portrayed as small](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/287588) and the guarantees of netfilter are [said to be "equivalent to what iptables-restore provides"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/599139)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Netfilter-persistent scripts use `iptables-restore` tool, that makes atomic reloading of an iptables rule set.
2. Netfilter-persistent scripts during a boot are run before interfaces will be bringing up (you can check output of `systemctl cat netfilter-persistent.service`).